# Magento Enterprise 1.13 always has all indexes in "ready" status

Tags: magento

I have Magento Enterprise 1.13. After installation I have some indexes in `reindex required` status and some in `scheduled` status.
[image]

I manually launched indexer.php with option `--reindexall` and index table became
[image]

But in further operations that require reindex - this table does not change his view. All indexes remained in `ready` status. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your root/var and root/media folder permission is it writable?

In magento re-indexing some time your database is updated well as per re-index structure but because of your folders permission issue the status of re-indexing remains required or processing so please check that after given permission to this two folder it will show in green means re-index is proper